# Get only first 5 items of a list in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have some data in the format as shown below in `pipelineRDD`:

```
[('x1', [('x2',1), ('x3',2),('x4',3),('x5',4)]),('x2',[('x1',3),('x4',3)])]
```

I want to filter the list of values for each key so that only the *first 5 values* from the value list is selected for each key.

how can I achieve this with having to `collect()`?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: For starters you should probably be using dictionaries for key: value structures. Why are you not?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)